# Importing a source dependency with Gradle (Kotlin DSL)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to import version 1.0.0 of this project https://github.com/whichdigital/ksv
as a [source dependency](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies) in a Kotlin project using Gradle 6.3 with Kotlin DSL.

As the page tells me I added this into the **settings.gradle.kts** of my project

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(java.net.URI.create("https://github.com/whichdigital/ksv.git")) {
        producesModule("uk.co.whichdigital:ksv")
    }
}
```

and using this dependency in my **build.gradle.kts** file:

```
implementation("uk.co.whichdigital:ksv:1.0.0")
```

trying to import tagged version/release 1.0.0 of the KSV repo. But building my project (importing the KSV repo) fails with following expection:

```
TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':bootJar'.
...
Caused by: DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
....
Caused by: ModuleVersionResolveException: Git repository at https://github.com/whichdigital/ksv.git did not contain a project publishing the specified dependency.
Required by:
    project :
```

I'm actually also the person who wrote/published the KSV-repository, so if there's some configuration that I missed, I can add it in the imported or importing project.

Comment: why don't you just download the source code and import as a module

Comment: because I want it to be an external dependency, (having it local would just tempt team members to modify its code locally instead of fixing the repository version). And now with the fix from Ramachandran Marugaian (by fixing the group id), i can :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "uk.co.whichdigital:ksv:1.0.0" group id is wrong.

Can you please try

```
sourceControl {
   gitRepository(java.net.URI.create("https://github.com/whichdigital/ksv.git")) {
     producesModule("uk.co.whichdigital.ksv:ksv")
   }
}
```

`implementation("uk.co.whichdigital.ksv:ksv:1.0.0")`

Comment: Just a FYI, this only works if the repository is public. If its private, you will get `Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered`. Also, it seems that they haven't yet incorporated a way to make it work with SSH for the authentication, but I could be wrong (even do I try to find it).